# How can I use tap event in Stackpanel's empty party?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, stackpanel, tap

I have a grid that has 4 Stackpanel child. I want to make visible other 3 stack panel with clicking first stackpanel and make collapsed with clicking other stackpanels. I am using Tap event in Stackpanel but it is not handled in empty parts of stackpanels.

How can I do it?

[image: My StackPanel]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your StackPanels don't actually extend to the area you marked. You would need to change them into Grids with Auto-sized ColumnDefinitions for the text content and a star-sized column to the right or simply wrap your StackPanels in Grids. Also make sure the Backgrounds of your panels are not null (default) - use a brush, even if it is Transparent and make sure IsHitTestVisible isn't set to false - otherwise your panels will be invisible to hit testing and won't be interactive.

Comment: Without changing StackPanels into Grids, your answer suggested me to set StackPanels' width to an explicit value and setting the backgroud to Transparent. This way I was able to handle the Tap event in the empty (no text inside) area of the control.